# Google Maps' custom marker doesnt have transparency

Tags: google-maps

I have a png image to place as a custom marker. Code is simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<div id="gmap" style="width:960px; height:360px;"></div>');
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(xxx, xxx);
    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("gmap"), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: map_center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        styles: [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "on" },
            { saturation: -100 }
          ]
        }]
    });

    var pos;
    var marker;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(xxx, xxx);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos,
          map: map,
          title: 'Tu jesteśmy',
          icon: 'pointer.png',
          optimized: false,
          shadow: 'shadow.png'
      });
    }
</script>
```

My problem is, neither `shadow.png` nor `pointer.png` has any PNG proporties. Both look like gifs. How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "both look like gifs"?

Comment: Crispy corners, no alpha channel.

Comment: Google Maps doesn't do any post-processing on your image assets, so you probably haven't saved them as 24-bit PNGs.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/h48ruJ4.png it has alpha channel, take a look.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/lBRruWI2fGy7lL1bES0Q?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating multiple markers at the same position, so while they *are* transparent, you have 10 stacked on top of one another which is giving the appearance of one fully opaque marker.

[Here's the updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IKGz7E9CKX8KCdYg6QSa?p=preview) with your loop reduced to a single iteration to get my point across.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now, since all that time I believied that there was `for(var i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++)`. Well, thank you very much for your help!